# Mirror Modifier Problem

Tags: mirror

I'm new to Blender and I'm currently trying to sculpt a bipedal dinosaur character, I decided to apply the mirror modifier to create the main body however when I try to transform the faces it creates this problem. All boxes in the modifier are checked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are talking about saying "this problem" is not so clear to me. But are you taking into account that mirror use the object's center (the big yellow dot) as pivot point for each mirror axis?

Comment: When I transform a face, the face transforms on the opposite side of the cube. The big yellow dot is in the center of the square.

Comment: What you describe sounds like it is the purpose of the mirror, not the problem. Can you describe in terms of what you expect to happen in contrast to what does happen? Use axes information, e.g. "I move a face on the extrem positive x of the object and on the extreme negative x another face moves, too." or "If I move a face on the exterme negative y, iexpect the twin face on the extreme positive y to also move."

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. The Mirror mod uses the object's origin as the point of reflection for left-right, front-back, and top-bottom (x, y and z axes). One problem I can see - as you say you have turned all mirror axes on - is that you have extruded or moved faces past the origin, which results in faces overlapping each other. This causes confusion later on. If you're modelling an animal with only one axis od symmetry, I suggest just using the x mirror axis, and don't extend faces, lines or vertices past the mirror point (origin).

Comment: You probably don't want to check *all* the boxes in the mirror modifier. Based on your scene, I advise you un-check *X* and *Z*.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, the problem appears to be solved. I deleted the box and made a new mirror modifier and only checked the box on the Y axis. The box extruded with no issues :)